# Name type returned by inner closure

Tags: typescript

I can't seem to figure out how to write a return type for this function, which works as expected, and typechecks as expected too (sans the *internal* todos). The fact that partially the type is on the inner closure is throwing me off.

Here's the *core* code, [full code here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGAwjgDbkBGOAxgNZwC+cAZlBCHAORTp0xuAbgBQoSLERxafPOgAiUHKxhFWwAHbBUAC0XL4Ldpx6gQ6KMJEiYATzDo4iiGABiwKKhgAeACpx0AA98DQATVBQNeg0IAHcNAG0AXQA+OABeOH8gkPC4BOQomPiiADpyzVYLOABVJJE4RrgAflqGpoAuOA10ADcLUREgiXhWQtoYYAgNYnQASRBzKG9sORSACk1gSYoANQpkdC7V-ABKRHbG2mmvfK85IgwYJIzZk-RNrR3yffJD09ETWkN3goW0YDwtB0rzQ6DIlBoDHWlyBcBwqFsGlobHGk2mcG8KNRTQAghMpjMcugwhF1vd8MdcPgyuUcFAAOaoLo4DS2c7pNK9CDAUJwAA+cAAChwQNp0N4hSKUgQicSsgFgtS8s43B4vN5JWycOZ8J5vGS8RoUsrVcSNgIKV0LRSWaU2Zyur5zghbajrhpbqElCpXjJ+Ph9Co6Uz0ADfUCAPQJuAAARgqAAtMN0BMs1AOFBuuh0KKYBA2MBAvGmjhYjhtmjydN1kGDK73ag42q-SCi7F3q91FpdJGYC3gzAu92mknU+ms4EHLmLAWiyW4GWK1Xp00nusev2Y1Od3wYMgoDMD+9AWqmCruwl6egkvemse4KfzzNHzGiGDUBCMBQi86LAgGMCiEw1iaKarB0I4ACytgDj6QIaMaRxwF4UCaOyN6NDg7KYRoyAgFQAwiFBIhjFilpYegMAAHIYdGchdEh7xEOh5hdNhuHeiiT6lNxjiZCJkHWDRTYzE8JJEaxDJwBxv5okRXQkWRFgCUCQmEaJqnoBJ1G4hScAkmAYDrNpTT+rcP4PHA-6AcBMIYAsSzrEgIldAARAAmhAoQ4D5RB6V0ACcAAMkXMO+TmQjodIMcx5hED5AAyyD0OgPlxeCCVJTAcmEHAACM0XvrOaaZtmy75tAG46NoG72I4UI5vQESgbV+ChCi8VAYlslEWljEuDlcZMEAA):

```js
type DropFirst<T extends unknown[]> = T extends [unknown, ...infer U]
    ? U
    : never;

export function useImmer<State>(initialValue: State) {
    const [state, set] = useState(initialValue);
    const dispatch = useCallback(
        async function <
            Action extends (state: State, ...args: any) => void | Promise<void>,
            T extends DropFirst<Parameters<Action>>,
            >(action: Action, ...args: T) {
            const draft = createDraft(state);
            // @ts-expect-error need to fix
            await action(draft, ...args);
            const newState = finishDraft(draft);
            // @ts-expect-error need to fix
            set(newState);
            return newState;
        },
        [state],
    );
    return [state, dispatch] as const;
}
```

I'd like to be able to write a return type like:

```js
export function useImmer<State>(initialValue: State): [State, Dispatcher<State>]
```

And similarly I'd like to be able to write a type of `Action<State>` if possible, for the first argument to the inner function.

I'm playing with the generated types but can't seem to split it up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky thing here is that your function is generic at declaration time (when `useImmer` is called), and at call time (when the callback is called). You can model this with a type like:

```
type MyFn<A> = <B>(a: A, b: B) => void
```

Or in your case, something like:

```js
type Dispatcher<State> =
    <
        Action extends (state: State, ...args: any) => void | Promise<void>,
        T extends DropFirst<Parameters<Action>>,
    >(
        action: Action,
        ...args: T
    ) => ReturnType<typeof finishDraft>
```

Which does what you expect here:

```
export function useImmer<State>(initialValue: State): [State, Dispatcher<State>] {
```

Now you can even vastly simply the callback, too.

```js
export function useImmer<State>(initialValue: State): [State, Dispatcher<State>] {
    const [state, set] = useState(initialValue);

    const dispatch = useCallback<Dispatcher<State>>(
        async function(action, ...args) {
            //...
```

[Typescript playground with working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=46&pln=16&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGAwjgDbkBGOAxgNZwC+cAZlBCHAORTp0xuAbgBQoSLERxafPOgAiUHKxhFFy1W2AA7YKgAW6lczYcu3UCHRRhIkTACeYdHEUQwAMWBRUMADwAKnDoAB742gAmqCja9NoQAO7aANoAugB8cAC8cEGh4VFwycix8UlEAHRVOqzWcACqqSJwLXAA-A3NrQBccNroAG7WovZOLvJ6YHi0+tZ+2HKZWV0tfiutLQCCtDDAENrBYeiR0QAUvnK9C-iVVThQAOaovTjaDgCU2ZkDEMARcAAfOAABTMenQfh+f3SBHWGzyRxOrg4nm8vj8wPuOCs+B8fm2u326Rh63SpzhrQEe20vQJ1NhGw2VQq9yevQC60+WUyACV0DBkFBtAExn5HM4IKwtLoDEYYOk7KEJPBWCUdtTiOgAJIgKxQea4fBknTAXYUABqFGQ6CuhvQ716yWuhFck2ms31zvSqUQ61o+18RQuNzgGBgPpyaCwdtOJrN5Et5Gt7xGG392kDETdMBm2U1ZEoNAYfgmqCmOY9BsWZIpLRwqAc2lobDVhO0pyp+1uLMeqE+CFrjPTmaUxhyMn4+Dl5ztKcHGwA9Au4AABGCoAC0SvQOy3UA4UD66HQ-xgEC0IXnlISOFNcE77Yio80zNZfdEjM-0gD8H6CWdeasCasrPqcT4aHOX6Mkuq7rluITOLu1gHkeJ5wGeF5Xi0YanH+zqQVBrR8AKQpHv+dofl+TAMl+yTBugqQ0S0BEtMRgoHHRdpEFmZbuqkohMHYOi4qwdAuAAsg4AEDhs2jYjaoYwFAOgPJRdYPAp2jICAVDDCIgkiKqTZtqG-IAHLyTOlxwJJzpEHJVi9L4ynaA8-brPRFQOS4OTeQJdhGeq+ymTAmwaVZ+C9LZXH3hpvRaTp1juRsnk4BpeZpeg-mGa2GqbGAYCnMlrTDvAnFyNx2YzBGmo6nqpxIN5vQAEQAJoQBEODNUQmW9AAnAADANzAsXAPHljM5zmfJRDNQAMsg9DoM1o3je6U2hRpRAAIxDaNMFrpu25Ifu0DofoejoWM0izAw0T1ociH4BE6xrRWG1hS6zVme4y1zkwQA)

---

And you can simplify this even further.

You notice that in this type:

```js
type Dispatcher<State> =
    <
        Action extends (state: State, ...args: any) => void | Promise<void>,
        T extends DropFirst<Parameters<Action>>,
    >(
        action: Action,
        ...args: T
    ) => ReturnType<typeof finishDraft>
```

that `T` is never actually *used*. The `args` have that type, but you never reference the type of `args`. That means you don't need that to be generic.

That means we can reduce that to this:

```js
type Dispatcher<State> = <Action extends (state: State, ...args: any) => void | Promise<void>>(
    action: Action,
    ...args: DropFirst<Parameters<Action>>
) => ReturnType<typeof finishDraft>
```

And that can be made a lot more readable by abstracting the action function signature to it's own type:

```js
type ActionType<State> = (state: State, ...args: any) => void | Promise<void>

type Dispatcher<State> = <Action extends ActionType<State>>(
    action: Action,
    ...args: DropFirst<Parameters<Action>>
) => ReturnType<typeof finishDraft>
```

Much nicer!

[Playground with refactoring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=36&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGAwjgDbkBGOAxgNZwC+cAZlBCHAORTp0xuAbgBQoSLERxafPOgAiUHKxhFWwAHbBUAC0XL4Ldpx6gQ6KMJEiYATzDo4iiGABiwKKhgAeACpx0AA98DQATVBQNeg0IAHcNAG0AXQA+OABeOH8gkPC4BOQomPiiADpyzVYLOABVJJE4RrgAflqGpoAuOA10ADcLURt7RwBBWhhgCA1fYe9sOTTMgAovOS75-DLynCgAc1QunA1bAEoMtN6IYFC4AB84AAUOEG10b0vrlOs7BydtMDwtB0FjmuHwizg3jGEymAWC6DCEWhk2msw26BSKSW7UaAhRXWRUwIOLg5VKO32XWcbg8Xm8Dx2OHM+E8UPGKMxIjO6TSACV0DBkFBUQ5vD90BBWGxNNo9EoVF8REEJPBWIV2bC0OgAJIgcxQUELJYyiYUABqFGQ6HWYPQJy6CXRRHk-0BwIN6JSSUQJNoUy8+VWmzgGBg3syWvRxq0pvIFvIVpOgya0n98FCrpgQIyxHQZEoNAY3hdqABWfdhvBWJJKZwqFsGlobHVMI0SzxRNJ2z2qDOCBrKaafo0AdC8vgmRk-Hw+hUK1tSYHg7gAHoV3AAAIwVAAWmV6HGe6gHCg3XQ6BuMAg0sCS8HOFiOGA8A7bbHBi25J7i+Xy+HAZ6WJ0RzdQtF0WcYCWd8VB-X8UzXTdtz3QIHEPCwTzPC84CvG87xTUMlkA9FYLgxo+EFYUzyA21RDgphiTghIg3QJIGKaEi4HIoUNEDW0iAzUs3SSUQmGsTQWVYOhHAAWVsYD+xTDQmWtEMYCgTRdlopocF2FSNGQEAqAGERRJENVG1bEMBQAOWU+c1jgWSnW6ZSui8dSNF2PsSWY0olPMHN-PQETrHMjUeNDEZdPs-Auicvi4B0vSDKMqBvPw21yV0nMkpCsyWxROARjAMAlnSoc014uR+MzIFw1zXV9SWJAgq6AAiABNCBQhwNqiCSroAE4AAZhuYDiBLLIEVhs5SiDagAZZB6HQNqJtqnQZpgKLCDgABGUaOIQrdd33NDj2gbCdG0bDhmkYEGAiOs4VQ-BQhJSa3S2nb5uslxVsXJggA)

Comment: Absolutely brilliantly answered. The breakdown took me thru the whole experience. Thank you!